# Using Group Policy create Local Port that points to C:\scanbookdata\epl.txt

Tags: group-policy, port, drivers, printer

I'm trying deploy a local port printer which points to c:\scanbookdata\epl.txt using Group Policy.

Below is screen shot of what I'm trying to do :

[image]

I'm lost as how to go about this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file to create the printer port and use a login script GPO on the computer settings to handle this.  The below is VERY rudimentary (meaning it works fine, but would run at every login).

```
@echo off
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports" /v "C:\scanbookdata\epl.txt" /t reg_sz

net stop spooler
net start spooler
```

If you want to create an actual printer that prints to it we would need to know what kind of printer/driver and OS really.

I would look at using something like the prnmngr.vbs script http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868.aspx if necessary or a GPP to deploy the printer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754824.aspx

Comment: ic... so it looks like I could just add to registry using GPP. My next step would be add the printer using GPP as you have mentioned.  I'm a bit lost on what to put on Port & Printer Path field while adding Local Printer Item.

Comment: I got it resolved.  Shared & Listed the printer in Print Server.  Then set GPP Local Printer Item to Port-C:\scanbookdata\epl.txt & Port Path-browse to the shared printer.